# Jupyter Notebook: how to use ipython widget variable outside the function

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, widget, ipython

I am using the interact function of ipython widget and I want to use the selection as a variable outside the function. For e.g.

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive
list1 = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']

@interact
def uni_systems(items = list1):
    choice = items
```

It gives me an interactive dropout. Now I like to use choice or my dropout selection outside the function, but it is not defined yet. How to use it outside the function for any further processing

Comment: Did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, insert `global choice` statement before assigning a value in it within the function. Basically, creating it as a global variable so you can use it outside the function

Comment: Any other way, I would like to avoid global variables

Answer (score 0):

One solution, encapsulated slightly better than a global variable, is to assign the result to an attribute of the function:

```
@interact
def uni_systems(items = list1):
    uni_systems.choice = items

uni_systems('foo')
print(uni_systems.choice)
```

Trying access the result before the function has been called for the first time will raise an `AttributeError`.